# Retrieve user login e-mail and use it to pre-populate submission form

Tags: web2py

Using a web2py company/client app, I have an access-restricted section (@auth.requires_membership) - the user can login using their e-mail/password combination which gives access to a submission form. That form has an e-mail field, that I would like to have pre-populated (and not writable) with the e-mail the user used to login.
The form is supposed to have an optional attachment; depending on if a user attaches a document or not different e-mails are supposed to be send out.
I do not know how I can retrieve the user e-mail from the login form and use it to pre-populate the submission form?

Many thanks for any pointers!!!

These are my controllers

```
def eap():
error_form = SQLFORM(db.errorform, formstyle='bootstrap3_stacked')
error_form.element(_type='submit')['_class']='btn btn-primary btn-darkblue'
error_form.element('textarea[name=Error_report]')['_style'] = 'resize:none;'
for label in error_form.elements('label'):
    label["_style"] = "display:none;"
if error_form.process().accepted:
    eapparty = str(error_form.vars.email)
    info = str(error_form.vars.Error_report)
    filename = str(error_form.vars.errorattach)
    subject = str(error_form.vars.subject)
    mail.send(to=[eapparty], message= 'Thank you for submitting your query to us.' + '\n' + 'We will get back to you shortly.' +
    'Please do not directly respond to this message.''\n \n'
    + 'Your original message to us:' + '\n \n' + '"' + info + '"', subject=subject)
    if filename:
        original_filename, filepath = db.errorform.errorattach.retrieve(error_form.vars.errorattach)
        mail.send(to=['xyz@123.com'], message= eapparty + ' submitted a query' +
    '\n' + '"' + info + '"', subject= eapparty + " " + subject, attachments=mail.Attachment(filepath, original_filename))
    else:
        mail.send(to=['xyz@123.com'], message= eapparty + ' submitted a query' +
    '\n' + '"' + info + '"', subject= eapparty + ' ' + subject)
return dict (form=error_form)

def user():
return dict(form=auth())
```

This is my model

```
db.define_table('errorform', Field('subject',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Please provide a subject line'), widget=widget(_placeholder='Subject', _readonly=False)),
Field('Error_report', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Please input your query'),
widget=widget(_placeholder='Your query here', _readonly=False)),
Field('errorattach', 'upload', autodelete=True),
Field('email', requires=IS_EMAIL(error_message='Please provide your
e-mail'), widget=widget(_placeholder='Your e-mail (required)', 
_readonly=False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick - 
in the controller I had

```
def eap():
...
if error_form.process().accepted:
eapparty = str(error_form.vars.email)
...
```

and changed it to

```
def eap():
...
if error_form.process().accepted:
eapparty = auth.user.email
...
```

In the models I simply removed the option to enter an e-mail address altogether.
This bit got removed

```
,Field('email', requires=IS_EMAIL(error_message='Please provide your
e-mail'), widget=widget(_placeholder='Your e-mail (required)', 
_readonly=False))
```

- this way forms can only ever be submitted with the users login e-mail address and not an alternative one.